# I deleted searchd file from /usr/local/bin/ how to bring it back

Tags: sphinx

i installed sphinx search on centos 6.4 but i accidentally deleted the searchd 
file from

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

and now when i am trying to run the following command

```
/usr/local/bin/searchd --config /path/to/sphinx.conf
```

it obviously says that the file is not there

i searched through google but i did not find anything that could help me
please advise me on how to proceed in order to have searchd file back to its directory

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall sphinx the same way you did the first time. It should restore the file.

It wont overwrite your settings etc, but keep a seperate copy of sphinx.conf in case.

Comment: i just did and it did not restore it

Comment: any other ideas please?